# iOS Status bar overlay and PhoneGap build

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to make this config work with PhoneGap build server:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#7fbfd3" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />

<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

It works fine when I use cordova build but no luck with PhoneGap build server for now. Plugin is vailable from JS, color is applied but there is no additional space for status bar. I've tried both org.apache.cordova.statusbar and com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar. Any ideas how to make it work with PhoneGap build server?

Here is rest of installed plugins and preferences set

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="com.ququplay.websocket.websocket" version="0.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It [won't work with Hydration](https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin/issues/43) if you're using that; otherwise it should, but not all preferences...
I've shared a similar issue to PGB support today. Here my ticket:

The plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar not works correctly on PGB.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
```

Some configuration preferences are not considered on build. I've setted on config.xml following common preferences:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#0ff000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

I've tested on phonegap CLI, it works fine.

On PGB the iOS StatusBar overlays the webview. But if I turn off the overlays programmatically using the plugin's API, it works fine, and I can see the green StatusBar as setted on preferences,... but not the style default (dark text) also setted on preferences.

I've also tested the previous plugin source but it raises same results:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" source="pgb" />
```

I've created an App HelloWorld only for that purpose: 1493471

FYI, I've also tested the deprecated Plugin com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar, it considers the StatusBarOverlaysWebView preference but not the others...

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and i found out that WKWebView has some bugs with position css styling. Using de the default Webview will solve your overlay problem.

However, Im still trying to find a solution that works with WKWebView.